# How can I get access logs from TMG? (e.g,. GET method requests)

Tags: webserver, iis, windows-server-2008

I'm using QRadar as a SIEM solution. I want to integrate TMG logs so that I can obtain/search GET requests with specific extensions (e.g., `.jpg`, `.html`, `.php`).

I know in Apache you can get this through web access logs.

Answer (score 2):

The following might help with parsing your Apache access log for GET requests:  [Analyzing Apache Log Files](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/logs/#.Ub7KmbWsh8E)

I haven't used TMG, but have done this with  `awk`. See section 1 in the link above for the Apache combined log format, and sections 2 and 3 for parsing examples which you might adapt.

You can also parse Apache logs with cross-platform scripting languages, like Perl: [ApacheLog::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~ewilhelm/ApacheLog-Parser-v0.0.1/lib/ApacheLog/Parser.pm)